# I want to start using ubuntu, but

Tags: games

I'm very tempted to start using ubuntu, but the only thing that holds me back is gaming.
I've heard gaming on ubuntu isn't as good as it is on windows.

Can anyone tell me why, or what can be done to make it better?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question may not be a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. Please have a look at the _[What kind of questions should I not ask here?](http://askubuntu.com/faq#dontask)_ section of the [faq]. Can you re-phrase this question and make it more specific, possibly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why? Because there's very few games available. Most of the games that you would play on Windows cannot be played on Ubuntu. There are some exceptions however, and with [Steam for Linux](http://steamcommunity.com/linux) now open more and more games are [becoming available](http://store.steampowered.com/search/?os=linux)

There is also the possibility of using [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/). It let's you install Windows programs on Linux. Things don't always work perfect but it is an option.

Another option is to [dual boot Ubuntu with Windows](http://lifehacker.com/5403100/dual+boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-in-perfect-harmony). This way, if you ever want to play video games you can just restart into Windows and do your thing. If you have no experience with Linux this might be your best bet. I don't know how much you know about computers, but it took a couple months of me playing with Ubuntu while still using Windows as my main OS before I was comfortable enough to make the switch. It's beyond worth it. I could never go back to using Windows as my main OS again.

Comment: Thank you for the info.

It seems like I need to play around with it and see how and what might work! :)

Wish me luck!

Comment: Don't forget native Ubuntu games. There are some free ones listed here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Games/NativeFreeUbuntuGames and many available in the software center (some for a fee).